# Certbot SSL error "Unrecognized challenges: tls-sni"

Tags: ssl, certbot

When I am trying to create an SSL certificate on port 443, I get the following error:

```
certbot: error: argument --preferred-challenges: Unrecognized challenges: tls-sni
Port 80 is already in use, so I am following the instructions of using “–preferred-challenges tls-sni” but it does not seem to be working.
```

I am using the following code in terminal:

```
certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges tls-sni -d <mydomain>.com --server "https://dv.acme-v02.api.pki.goog/directory" --standalone
```

Not sure if I am missing anything. Following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates-on-ubuntu-1804

Comment: Not programming or development but [GTS ACME supports only HTTP, TLS-ALPN, and DNS challenges](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/how-it-works#public-ca-challenges) -- not TLS-SNI. In fact nobody supports TLS-SNI anymore because it was found to be spoofable, and a comment near the bottom of the page you link notes that LetsEncrypt dropped TLS-SNI soon after the page was written. I recommend using documentation that [actually is for the Google CA](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/public-ca-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following command in a bash script dedicated to this task :

`certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges tls-alpn-01 --keep-until-expiring --cert-name ${CERT_NAME} -d ${DOMAIN_NAME}`

You have to set the 2 env vars just before...
and dns entries + webservers https config, of course.